# Enable a checkbox from a link

Tags: php, jquery

I have 4 links on a page that all link to a search page. The search page has a search box and 4 checkboxes for filters. What would be the best way to go about enabling a filter based on what link was clicked from another page. So if on the home page, link 2 was clicked, the 2nd option would be checked on the search page. I'm using php and jQuery but not sure how I would pass the options from one page to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `GET` http protocol and obtain information directly from the url with a custom method [`$.urlParam`](http://nack.co/get-url-parameters-using-jquery/), on each subsequent *"search page"*.

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to pass a query parameter through the URL of each hyperlink. For instance:

```
<a href="search.php?filter=1">Search page</a>
```

Then on the search page, you can use either PHP or jQuery to read this query parameter and take the appropriate action.

PHP Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filter1"<?php
if(isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] == 1){
    print "checked";
}
?> /> Filter 1
```